# How can I tell Rails to not encode special characters in a string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this:

```
"<img src='#{picture.url(:tiny)}'>"
```

Which is output like this:

```
 &lt;img src='/system/pictures/2/tiny/Womacdsf.jpg?1294942797'&gt;, &lt;img src='/system/pictures/3/tiny/Womacdsf_3017.jpg?1294942797'&gt;, &lt;img src='/system/pictures/4/tiny/Womacdsf_8012.jpg?1294942797'&gt;, … (8)
```

As you can see, this is encoding using `&lt;` and `&gt;` instead of using the raw `<` and `>`.

How can I tell Rails this is not what I want?

Answer (score 4):

using

```
<%= image_tag picture.url(:tiny) %>
```

should work

for your problem you can also use this

```
"<img src='#{picture.url(:tiny)}'>".html_safe
```

Comment: +1 for the image tag, if only for the timestamps that come with

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Rails 3, XSS protection is on by default. That means that HTML is escaped by default.

Where you might have once used the "h" helper to generate escaped HTML, you no longer need to, but instead will need to use the "raw" helper to prevent escaping.

See http://asciicasts.com/episodes/204-xss-protection-in-rails-3

Answer (score 2):

You have two options. Either un-escape the string using `raw` when you print it

```
<% image_string = "<img src='#{picture.url(:tiny)}'>" %>
<%= raw image_string %>
```

Or you can mark the string as `html_safe`

```
<% image_string = "<img src='#{picture.url(:tiny)}'>".html_safe %>
<%= image_string %>
```